# Why will I have operand type mismatch error when compiling the assembly codes with gcc?

Tags: gcc, assembly, g++

The following codes are used for calculate the `sin` and `cos` value if the angle is given. In order to  calculate these functions as fast as possible, assembly code implementations are adopted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float sinx( float degree ) {
    float result, two_right_angles = 180.0f ;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "fld %1;"
                            "fld %2;"
                            "fldpi;"
                            "fmul;"
                            "fdiv;"
                            "fsin;"
                            "fstp %0;" 
                            : "=g" (result) 
                            : "g"(two_right_angles), "g" (degree)
    ) ;
    return result ;
}

float cosx( float degree ) {
    float result, two_right_angles = 180.0f, radians ;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "fld %1;"
                            "fld %2;"
                            "fldpi;"
                            "fmul;"
                            "fdiv;"
                            "fstp %0;" 
                            : "=g" (radians) 
                            : "g"(two_right_angles), "g" (degree)
    ) ;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "fld %1;"
                            "fcos;"
                            "fstp %0;" : "=g" (result) : "g" (radians)
    ) ;
    return result ;
}

float square_root( float val ) {
    float result ;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "fld %1;"
                            "fsqrt;"
                            "fstp %0;" 
                            : "=g" (result) 
                            : "g" (val)
    ) ;
    return result ;
}

int main() {
    float theta ;
    printf( "Enter theta in degrees : " ) ;
    scanf( "%f", &theta ) ;

    printf( "sinx(%f) = %f\n", theta, sinx( theta ) );
    printf( "cosx(%f) = %f\n", theta, cosx( theta ) );
    printf( "square_root(%f) = %f\n", theta, square_root( theta ) ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

The above codes comes from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C), and I am trying to compile the above codes with gcc:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g     -c /filename.cpp
```

However, it fails, and the following error messages are given:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `fstp'|
Error: operand type mismatch for `fstp'|
```

I was wondering why the compilation would fail and how I can compile them successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html) says about `g` constraint: `Any register, memory or immediate integer operand is allowed, except for registers that are not general registers`. The compiler probably picked a register which `fstp` doesn't accept but fits the constraints.

By the way, this is quite horrible inline asm.

Also note just because something is in asm, it will not necessarily be faster. The compiler is quite capable of optimizing things and it does a better job, too. You might be interested in the `-ffast-math` switch. From `return sin(degree * M_PI / 180);` the compiler produces this small piece of code:

```
fldl    .LC0
fmuls   4(%esp)
fsin
ret
```

Comment: I am now replacing 'g' with 'm', and it can compile successfully. I will compare this implementation with your suggested method. Thanks!